# how to interpret the boundaries of this solid

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I have a question:

Use polar coordinates to find the volume of the given solid.

Below the plane $2x + y + z = 4$ and above the disk $x^2 + y^2 <= 1$

I know I'm supposed to take the double integral of $z = -2x - y + 4$ but I'm not sure how to interperet the disk equation and make it the boundaries in my double integral. If someone could give a clear explanation of how it works that'd be great, my books example doesn't really explain it well, at least not for this situation.

edit: i accidently wrote the wrong plane equation

Comment: Disk on which plane thou? $z=0$?

Answer (score 0):

The comment about the $z=0$ plane is relevant, but in your question you construe $z$ as $z=f(x,y)$ implicitly stating that you are integrating values of $f$, so is, infinitesimal volumes $f(x,y)\,\mathbb dy\,\mathbb dx$, the heigh of which is the distance from the plane $z=0$ to $z=f(x,y)$

You have the equation for the disk boundary, so you can express the value of $y$ in the boundary for any $x$: into the disk, $x$ ranges from $-1$ to $1$ and for each $x$, $y$ ranges from $-\sqrt{1-x^2}$ to $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ (this values are for the disk boundary). So,

$$V=\int_{-1}^1\int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}(-2x-y+4)\,\mathbb dy\,\mathbb dx$$

Comment: So did you get 1 and -1 just by finding out for what values of x make y=0? and how does this problem differ from a disk with $x^2 + y^2 = 1? Specifically, what does the <= entail?

Comment: $1$ and $-1$ come from the range for $x$ in $y=\pm\sqrt{1-x^2}$. The equation you wrote in your comment doesn't define a disk but its boundary.